# Is this sound made by 'Flipper' dolphin tv series real?

Tags: identification, dolphins, call-identification, fictional-sounds

Flipper was a [tv show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipper_(1964_TV_series)) in the 60s about a dolphin and his humans. There is this sound that flipper supposedly makes out of water that is unlike any other dolphin sound I have heard (I have studied underwater acoustics of pelagic dolphins for a long time). I have always wondered if this is a sound that dolphins may make in the air? Or perhaps they can be  trained to make this sound? Or perhaps this sound is synthetic/fake?

**Does anyone know if this is a real sound that dolphins make?**

[Link to sound on youtube](https://youtu.be/UccklcLIhGE).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Washington Post [reports](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/2003/01/31/day-of-the-dolphin/493063d2-ef69-42d5-952a-73e7a8b4c20b/) that according to Jennifer Durkin from the Baltimore's National Aquarium:

> The friendly voice of the dolphin in "Flipper" was dubbed -- it was,
> in fact, a recording of Australia's [kookaburra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kookaburra) bird.

Check out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqdRQxgtZtI), they sound similar to Flipper indeed :-)

Comment: That is amazing--- over the years I have periodically become re-obsessed with this question & never found any info on it.... Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi @Shannon you can "accept" this answer, I think, to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a recording of a Aussie Kookaburra, additional it was sped up a bit.